# Looping datatable for assigning values to a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have a `gridview`, in which there are multiple `columns` and `rows`.

While debugging it generates `datatable` as below

[image: Datatable]

and its query is

```
DataTable dttable2 = new DataTable();
    dttable2 = CF.ExecuteDT("select cr.Mkey, cr.Rating1,cr.Rating2,cr.Rating3,cr.Rating4 from p_emp_Company_Rating cr  "+
                            "join p_emp_Exit_Interview ei on ei.Mkey=cr.Mkey where ei.mkey='" + HidMKey.Value + "'");
```

I want to loop it as much as it contains rows.

I tried with below code but it is going once and coming out.

```
string strgrid1 = string.Empty;

    if (dttable2.Rows.Count > 0)
    { 
        /** Job security **/
        if (dttable2.Rows[0]["Rating1"].ToString() == "Y")
        {
            strgrid1 = "Poor";
        }
        if (dttable2.Rows[0]["Rating2"].ToString() == "Y")
        {
            strgrid1 = "Satisfactory";
        }
        if (dttable2.Rows[0]["Rating3"].ToString() == "Y")
        {
            strgrid1 = "Good";
        }
        if (dttable2.Rows[0]["Rating4"].ToString() == "Y")
        {
            strgrid1 = "Excellent";
        }
    }
```

Below is screenshot of the gridview

[image: Grid]

how to loop it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a `foreach` loop instead of an `if` statement.

```
string strgrid1 = string.Empty;

foreach (DataRow row in dttable2.Rows)
{ 
    /** Job security **/
    if (row["Rating1"].ToString() == "Y")
    {
        strgrid1 = "Poor";
    }
    if (row["Rating2"].ToString() == "Y")
    {
        strgrid1 = "Satisfactory";
    }
    if (row["Rating3"].ToString() == "Y")
    {
        strgrid1 = "Good";
    }
    if (row["Rating4"].ToString() == "Y")
    {
        strgrid1 = "Excellent";
    }
}
```

Comment: at `row` getting error as `cannot apply indexing with to an expression of type object`

Comment: Sorry. I forgot that you must explicitly declare the row to be a `DataRow` when working with DataTables. Try that.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try For Loop to achieve desired results.

```
string strgrid1 = string.Empty;

if (dttable2.Rows.Count > 0)
{ 
    /** Job security **/
    for(int i = 0; i < dttable2.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
       if (dttable2.Rows[i]["Rating1"].ToString() == "Y")
       {
        strgrid1 = "Poor";
       }
       if (dttable2.Rows[i]["Rating2"].ToString() == "Y")
       {
        strgrid1 = "Satisfactory";
       }
       if (dttable2.Rows[i]["Rating3"].ToString() == "Y")
       {
        strgrid1 = "Good";
       }
       if (dttable2.Rows[i]["Rating4"].ToString() == "Y")
       {
        strgrid1 = "Excellent";
       }
    }
}
```